# Assigning JavaScript primitives to their named equivalent variable like "constants"

Tags: javascript, qtip

I was looking at the source code to [qTip 2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) and saw the following:

```
// Munge the primitives - Paul Irish tip
var TRUE = true,
   FALSE = false,
    NULL = null;
```

I can't come up with a reason you should ever do this, and have a strong feeling that it would just encourage bad coding habits. Say a developer makes a typo in a Yoda condition like `if (TRUE = someCondition())`, then `TRUE` could very well end up actually meaning `false`, or you might end up assigning `someObject` to `NULL`.

I guess I'm just wondering if there's some redeeming quality for this practice that I'm missing, or if this is just a plain old Bad Idea™

Comment: Btw, `+1` not only for the good question but for using the term *Yoda condition*..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: You might be interested in this article, then :) -http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html

Comment: Hmm, actually get work done or read funny coding blog.  Blog it is!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The goal of this is just to improve compression, Paul Irish himself calls it as an "Anti-Pattern".

He describes it as *"Good for compression and scope chain traversal"* on the following presentation:

- [jQuery Anti-Patterns for Performance & Compression](http://www.slideshare.net/paul.irish/perfcompression) (slide [46](http://www.slideshare.net/paul.irish/perfcompression/46))

On scope chain traversal, we won't see any improvement on literals as `null`, `false`, `true`, since the scope chain is not inspected, they are just literals.

On other identifiers as `undefined` or `windows` the scope chain traversal is indeed inspected.

[image: Paul Irish Anti-patterns slide 55]

Comment: I wonder if it's worth it at all if you gzip. I seem to recall cases where the obfuscated result was indeed smaller, but the gzipped result was larger than the equivalent gzip without the munging.

Comment: @missingno - qTip got the idea from this slide. They put it write there in the comment (see the first line in the OP's code).

Comment: @amnotiam: that's a great question, I'd be interested in seeing some real world comparisons

Comment: @cms, may I request to have a look at a jquery question on a different topic  here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137404/jquery-find-div-class-name-at-a-certain-position-while-scrolling ?

Answer (score 4):

You could do this for the sake of code compression. For example, YUI Compressor is not going to touch `true` and `false`, but it could replace all occurrences of, for example, `TRUE` with `A`, saving four characters per occurrence. For example, before compression:

```
    if (foo === null) {
        bar = true;
    }
```

After compression, assuming the compressor replaces `TRUE` with `a` and `NULL` with `c`:

```
if(foo===c){bar=a;}
```

Versus this, after compression with no "munging of primitives":

```
if(foo===null){bar=true;}
```

The bad-coding-habits danger that you quite correctly cite in your question may outweigh the small savings in additional compression. It depends on how desperate you are to save a few dozen or perhaps a few hundred bytes.

Personally, I would (*almost*) never do this. Too dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is recommended for compression.

These shortcut variables will be compressed when munged, resulting in smaller files.  However, your noted drawbacks are most certainly valid points!