# jquery, find closest div which is not in any ancestry

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="find_div" id="some_id_1"></div>

<!-- other divs -->

<div class="find_div" id="some_id_2"></div>

    <!-- other divs -->


<div class="find_div" id="some_id_3"></div>

<!-- other divs -->

    <div class="target_div"></div>


<div class="find_div" id="some_id_4"></div>

<!-- other divs -->

<div class="find_div" id="some_id_5"></div>

    <!-- other divs -->


<div class="find_div" id="some_id_6"></div>

<!-- other divs -->
```

1) What is the way to find the  `find_div` which is closest to `target_div` ?

2) How to find other `find_div` divs that are less close consequtively ?

Note that there is no ancestral relation in the case being discussed .  Consequently jaquery `closest()` is not effective here i think.

I make this question after I asked a  question previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137404/jquery-find-div-class-name-at-a-certain-position-while-scrolling) with a related problem. Hope that does not make any duplication.

**EDIT:** Added few lines of code before the `target_div` line.

Comment: Your question become more and more interresting. I was just wondering seeing all nextAll() answers how to apply a such request for prev divs and next divs and counting discarded elements to get which one is effectively the 'closest' one(s).

Comment: divs before the `target_div` were added later in an edit. so only next divs are considered in the answers. sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) - grabs all following siblings that match the given selector

```
$('.target_div').nextAll('.find_div').first();// gets closest one after

$('.target_div').nextAll('.find_div').eq(0) // <-- index of where they are in the collection
```

**EDIT**

You will have to do some calculations of the previous and next div.. and see which one is closer by getting their position.

```
var $tdiv = $('.target_div');
var $prev = $tdiv.prevAll('.find_div').first();// prev .find_div div
var $nex = $tdiv.nextAll('.find_div').first();// next .find_div div
var closest;
// get distance between bottom of prev div and top of target div
var $prevDistance = $tdiv.position().top - ($prev.position().top + $prev.height());
// get distance between bottom of target div and top of next div
var $nexDistance = $nex.position().top - ($tdiv.position().top + $tdiv.height());

// if prev div distance is less than next div - closest == prev div
if ($prevDistance < $nexDistance) {
    closest = $prev;
} else {
    closest = $nex;
}
// now you can do whatver you want with the closest element
closest.dowhatever
// or if you want to do something to all others except closest
$('.find_div').not(closest).dowhatever
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c5gD9/)

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed How do you consider which one is closest?

Comment: depending on the distance between the two adjoining (even if not exactly adjoining  as other divs may exist in between) edges of two divs.

Comment: distance as in pixels? or distance as in the amount of children elements in between?

Comment: experimenting to user this idea to solve my problem. can you have a look at the linked SO question mentioned in my post  please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextAll:`

1)

```
$('.target_div').nextAll(".find_div").first()
```

2)

```
$('.target_div').nextAll(".find_div").not(':first')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since any transversal DOM method have a 'one-way direction', your best bet seems to start from 'body' tag element and descent in DOM to grab all elements.
This should be optimised but to get you the general idea, look at following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsCFL/):
(in case of equality, this return 2 DOM elements)

```
 var domElems = $('body').find('*'),
    index = 0,
    targetIndex, prevIndex, nexttIndex, grabbedElems = [],
    results = [];

for (var i = 0, z = domElems.length; i < z; i++) {
    index++;
    if ($(domElems[i]).is('.find_div')) grabbedElems[index] = $(domElems[i]);
    else if ($(domElems[i]).is('.target_div')) targetIndex = index;
}

for (var i = 0, z = grabbedElems.length; i < z; i++) {
    if (grabbedElems[i]) {
        if (i < targetIndex) prevIndex = i;
        else if (i > targetIndex) {
            nextIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (Math.abs(prevIndex - targetIndex) <= Math.abs(nextIndex - targetIndex)) results.push(grabbedElems [prevIndex]);

if (Math.abs(nextIndex - targetIndex) <= Math.abs(prevIndex - targetIndex)) results.push(grabbedElems [nextIndex]);

if (results.length > 0) console.log(results[0]);
if (results.length > 1) console.log(results[1]);​
```

Comment: I feel easy with jquery instead of raw js however.

Comment: oh, ya  you used jquery ... hmm

Comment: let me experiment with the answer. can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137404/jquery-find-div-class-name-at-a-certain-position-while-scrolling please?